# I need to animate the concetric circles on a canvas FabricJs using recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, fabricjs

I have 10 concentric circles that i want to animate using **FabricJs Canvas**.
My goal is that the 1st inner circle should show itself first then and the 2nd, and so on by using recursion or some other techniques to avoid code duplication.
I have managed to animates two 1st inner circles but with redundant code.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {
  selection: false
});

fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

let circles = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  drawCircles();
});

document.getElementById('animateBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
 animateCircles();
});

function makeCircle(r) {
  return new fabric.Circle({
    left: 300,
    top: 120,
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    radius: r,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    selectable: false,
    hoverCursor: 'default',
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false
  });

}

function drawCircles()
{
   for(let i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
     {
       let circle  = makeCircle(10*(i + 1));
         circles.push(circle);
         canvas.add(circle);
     }
   
     
}

function animateCircles()
{
    canvas.clear();
  
    
    circles[9].animate({
            opacity: 1
        },
        {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInElastic'],
            onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
            onComplete: function () {

                circles[9].setCoords();
                canvas.add(circles[9]);
                canvas.renderAll();
                circles[8].animate({
                    opacity: 1
                },
                {
                    duration: 2000,
                        easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInElastic'],
                        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                        onComplete: function () {
                            circles[8].setCoords();
                                canvas.add(circles[8]);
                                canvas.renderAll();
                                //On this line i need to use the code for animation
                        }
                }
                
                );
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

#animateBtn {
    margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="240" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
  <button id="animateBtn">Start Animation</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function `loop(i)` which has the repeating code (so without the initial `clear()` call) for *one* circle. Let `i` be the index of the circle. Then in the `onComplete` callback, call that `loop`, but now with argument `i-1`. Add a stop condition (when `i` would become negative).

Here is your code with that implementation:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('gameCanvas', {
  selection: false
});

fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

let circles = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', drawCircles);
document.getElementById('animateBtn').addEventListener('click', animateCircles);

function makeCircle(r) {
  return new fabric.Circle({
    left: 300,
    top: 120,
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    radius: r,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    selectable: false,
    hoverCursor: 'default',
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: false
  });
}

function drawCircles() {
    for (let i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        let circle  = makeCircle(10*(i + 1));
        circles.push(circle);
        canvas.add(circle);
    }
}

function animateCircles() {
    canvas.clear();
    
    function loop(i) {
        if (i < 0) return; // end the asynchronous loop
        circles[i].animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 300,
            easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInElastic'],
            onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
            onComplete: function () {
                circles[i].setCoords();
                canvas.add(circles[i]);
                canvas.renderAll();
                loop(i - 1);
            }
        });
    }
    
    loop(9); // start the asynchronous loop
}
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

#animateBtn {
    margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="240" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
  <button id="animateBtn">Start Animation</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes this works! How can i make the inner circle stay visible on the canvas ? I appreciate mate

Comment: That is a different question. Draw the inner circle (number 9) separately, and start the "loop" with 8? If you cannot make it work, then just ask a new question about it.

Comment: Not at all! I appreciate mate!